# Webview sound in Android

Tags: android, webview, audio

I have a WebView in my application, this webview contain videos, but the problems is you can still hear the video's playing even you press the back menu.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6230902/943811).
Itseems the Webview thread continues to run even if you press back button.
You can read the answers in this SO question: [How to stop youtube video playing in Android webview?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5946698/943811)