# Android:Html 5 Video does not stop on activity finish

Tags: android, html, video, webview

I have created one android activity and in that i have a web view. I have given a html5 file path to webview.

Html 5 file contains a Video Tag in which I am calling android compatible mp4 video from server like: "http://xxx/test/abc.mp4".

Video plays nicely in webview but when video is in buffering mode and  i close the webview or close the activity by pressing back button on android tablet, then after that video still plays in backgroud even if activty is finished.

When i close the activity and video is in play mode(not in buffering mode) then video stops properly without any problem.

I have tried to close the webview thread as mentioned in:"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5946698/how-to-stop-youtube-video-playing-in-android-webview" but no luck....

Please please help on this. I am stuck in the issue from last 5 days.

Thanks in advance...
Ketan

Answer (score 2):

Raneez Ahmed's answer is correct. However, if you are developing for API level 11 or above, you can access WebView.onPause directly without reflection:

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    webview.onPause();
    super.onPause();
}
```

Remember to also implement onResume:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    webview.onResume();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Refer this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6230902/1219456)

The only way is to call WebView's onPause method from your own Activity's onPause method

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    try {
        Class.forName("android.webkit.WebView")
                .getMethod("onPause", (Class[]) null)
                            .invoke(webview, (Object[]) null);

    } catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
    ...
    } catch(NoSuchMethodException nsme) {
    ...
    } catch(InvocationTargetException ite) {
    ...
    } catch (IllegalAccessException iae) {
        ...
    }
}
```