# YouTube link in WebView resumes playback when returning to foreground

Tags: android, youtube, android-webview

I have a fragment with a `WebView` that loads a YouTube link.
ex. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CeNMOYuICcM.

In the fragment's `onPause`, I added this to prevent the playback when the screen is not displayed:

```
webView.onPause();
webView.pauseTimers();
```

Then in the fragment's `onResume`, I added this to allow playback when the screen is re-displayed:

```
webView.onResume();
webView.resumeTimers();
```

(This is based on other SO posts such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25380464/2745495) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29671017/2745495)).

My concern is when I do the following steps:

1. Tap Play on the YouTube video
2. Send the app to background
3. **Wait** for some time
4. Return to the app

If the **wait** is quick (say 1s), on 4., the video autoplays on its own.
If the **wait** is long (about 3s or more), on 4., the video does not autoplay.

Why is there a difference?
I already added tried setting `setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture` to `true`, but the video still autoplays when the wait time is not long enough.

I would like the video to **never** autoplay.
Is there a way to do that?

*Test env:

Nexus 5 5.1.1, Nexus 9 6.0.

Android System WebView 53.0.2785.124.*