# close a video on background in an application Android

Tags: android, video, android-activity

I making an application android with two Activity.
My second Activity  contains an youtube video embed.
When I launch this activity and run this video it works.
But when I close my activity, if my video is playing, my activity is closed but I hear the sond of my video.
I think my video is not really closed and she is playing in background.

can you help me?

thank !

edit : I build a test in my MyActivity and I have the same problem.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements MBAdListener{

private FrameLayout layout;

/**
 * Called when the activity is first created.
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    RelativeLayout adViewContainer = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    layout = new FrameLayout(this);

    layout.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            Gravity.CENTER)
    );
    layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
    setContentView(layout);
    WebView content = new WebView(this);
    content.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            Gravity.CENTER
    ));
    content.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    content.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    content.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    content.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    content.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
    content.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    content.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    content.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
    content.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NARROW_COLUMNS);
    content.getSettings().setSavePassword(true);
    content.getSettings().setSaveFormData(true);
    content.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);

    layout.addView(content);

    content.loadData("<iframe width=\"320\" height=\"200\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/vCXRt0kQvUE?autoplay=1\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>", "text/html", "UTF-8");

}
```

Comment: How are you closing your Activities? Do you call `finish()` or ever provide any commands to the activity while closing?

Comment: To close my Activity, I use onPause(); onStop(); and onDestroy();

Comment: Those are just methods you overload to have control over the activity lifecycle at the various stages. See this link, you'll have to call `finish()` in order to destroy the activity: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#ShuttingDown

Comment: I test with this :
    `@Override
    public void finish() {
        Logger.e("onFinish");
        super.finish();
        active = false;
    }`
It doesn't work !

Comment: You're overriding `finish()` and are better off *calling* `finish()` from your `onStop()` method. If you want to print a log message override `onFinish()`

Comment: I test this also. I test another thing. I add my webview with my video embed in autoplay, when I click on closeButton, I call `layout.removeAllViews();` , my view is remove but not my video

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this and it works !!!!
See the following post about [How to stop youtube video playing in Android webview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5946698/how-to-stop-youtube-video-playing-in-android-webview)

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
  super.onPause();

  try {
    Class.forName("android.webkit.WebView")
      .getMethod("onPause", (Class[]) null)
      .invoke(webview, (Object[]) null);
  } catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
      ...
  } catch(NoSuchMethodException nsme) {
      ...
  } catch(InvocationTargetException ite) {
      ...
  } catch (IllegalAccessException iae) {
      ...
  }
}
```