# Youtube video not stopping in a webview inside a fragment with view pager

Tags: android

**Problem Statement:** 
I have a view pager with pager adapter containing 4 fragments. In the last fragment, I have a webview dedicated to play you tube embed videos. When video is been played and I scroll the viewpager or I exit the app by pressing back button (as I have a single activity), Video doesnt stop in a webview. I have seen one answer at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5946698/how-to-stop-youtube-video-playing-in-android-webview). It doesn't work. But my question is even if it works, where should I put that onPause code of the webview? 
I have tried it in onPageScrolled method of pager adapter but it doesn't work there either.
Any help is appreciated. TIA.

Comment: Did you solve it, I also meet this problem

Comment: @Sachin Did you get the solution? please post here if you find it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to pause your webview in your fragment. Don't forget to resume it or it won't work the second time:

```
@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    mWebView.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    mWebView.onPause();
}
```