# How to stop playing video while moving in fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-videoview, android-fragmentactivity

I'm playing a video in my fragment activity. While moving to next page in the fragment, the video is playing in the previous page. I need to stop the video while moving. **OnPause()** is not working for me as it is get called when im moving to third page.

Thanks in advance.....

Comment: Are you using pager i fragment ? If yes then implement ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener in this call back you will notify when user changes page and in this call back method you can stop playing video. I hope this helps you.

Comment: Yes, im using ViewPager, but i have final VideoView in my Fragment class. I ll try to access using Interface to stop the video.

Comment: Yes you have to create interface which tell that pageChange is done and now which you have to implement interface to handle events on fragment.

Comment: Roll no1 - In OnPageChangeListener its getting called after the new page opens, so im not able to stop the video of previous page...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Youtube video not stopping in a webview inside a fragment with view pager](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16939752/youtube-video-not-stopping-in-a-webview-inside-a-fragment-with-view-pager)