# How to stop the Sound play in Background in Android Webview

Tags: android, video, webview, background-music

When i play a video in android webview it play perfectly but when i press the back button or home key than it does not stop the sound. it play in background.

When i remove my application from recent apps than this sound is stop otherwise it play in background.

I try all the solution given in below link. but no one is working for me.
http://devsolvd.com/questions/how-to-stop-youtube-video-playing-in-android-webview

This problem is not occur in Android 4.1 
In android 4.4.2(Kitkat) webview plays sound in background.

My Code is

```
@Override
    protected void onResume()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();   

        if (onResumeCall)
        {
            webView.onResume();
            setContentsData();

            if (contentHolders.size() > 0)
                selectItem(currentIndex, 0, FIRST_PAGE);
        }



        onResumeCall = true;
        //webView.onResume();
        Log.i("OnREsume", "OnREsume");


    }

@Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        }

@Override
    public void onBackPressed()    //when back pressed then
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

I try many things but it is not working.
Plz Help Me.

Comment: Is it a youtube video?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5946698/how-to-stop-youtube-video-playing-in-android-webview

Comment: Can you show some code please?

Comment: This is not a youtube video

Comment: @Override
 protected void onPause() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onPause();
  webView.onPause();
  
      }

Answer (score 2):

```
    @Override
     public void onPause() {
       super.onPause();
       mWebView.onPause();
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this

```
@Override  
protected void onPause() {  
    m_WebView.reload();  

    super.onPause();  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to override onBackPressed buttton

```
public void onBackPressed() {
   mWebView.onPause();
   super.onPause();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, it's a code I used for a similar problem on 4.4.2:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() 
    {
        webView.clearView();
        webView.freeMemory();
        webView.removeAllViews();
        webView.destroy();

    try {
          Class.forName("android.webkit.WebView")
                        .getMethod("onPause", (Class[]) null)
                        .invoke(webView, (Object[]) null);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

Comment: What is internalBrowser here

Comment: Try it without the removeView part

Comment: Didn't understand your last comment

Comment: webView.clearView();     webView.freeMemory();   This method was deprecated

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I resolved by javascript, doing that:

```
@Override
public void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    webView.loadUrl("javascript:pauseSound()");
}

@Override
public void onResume(){
   super.onResume();
   webView.loadUrl("javascript:playSound()");
   webView.onResume();
}
```