# Webview OnPause is not being called inside a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, webview, android-viewpager

I have a viewpager who has a fragments that displays a webview (the webview has video) 
The problem is: i start the video then swipe to the next fragment, the video is still playing! even when i call fragment onPasue method along with webview onpause according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25380464/4196092):

```
 public void onPause() 
{
            super.onPause();
            Log.d("onPause", "onPause");
            mWebview.onPause();

}
```

the log print onPause but the video is still playing. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the swipe on the ViewPager using onTouchEvent and when you swipe from the screen with the Webview, pause the video.