# How to pause a WebView in flutter?

Tags: browser, flutter, webview, dart

I have added a webview plugin (official flutter plugin) for viewing webpages. 
One of the webpage has a youtube video playing and when I press the home button and the app goes into background. **But the problem is that the sound keeps on playing.** 
There are other sections in the application that contain some component playing sound or video.

So I want to know what can be done to pause the webview altogether once I move the app to background.

I am currently using this webview plugin: `webview_flutter: ^0.3.9+1`
There is no option in the plugin to pause the webview itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not possible from Dart using the `webview_flutter` plugin.
However, you can use my plugin [flutter_inappwebview](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview), which is a Flutter plugin that allows you to add inline WebViews or open an in-app browser window and has a lot of events, methods, and options to control WebViews.

It implements methods to pause/resume the WebView.

For Android, you can use `InAppWebViewController.android.pause` and `InAppWebViewController.android.resume` to pause and resume WebView.
You should implement `WidgetsBindingObserver` in your Widget and check `AppLifecycleState state` through `didChangeAppLifecycleState()` method.

If you need to pause/resume also JavaScript execution you can use `InAppWebViewController.pauseTimers`/`InAppWebViewController.resumeTimers` methods.

Here is an example with a YouTube URL:

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_inappwebview/flutter_inappwebview.dart';

Future main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => new _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  InAppWebViewController webView;

  @override
  void initState() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(this);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.removeObserver(this);
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    print('state = $state');
    if (webView != null) {
      if (state == AppLifecycleState.paused) {
        webView.pauseTimers();
        if (Platform.isAndroid) {
          webView.android.pause();
        }
      } else {
        webView.resumeTimers();
        if (Platform.isAndroid) {
          webView.android.resume();
        }
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('InAppWebView Example'),
        ),
        body: Container(
            child: Column(children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
              child: InAppWebView(
            initialUrl: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NfNdXgJZfFo",
            initialHeaders: {},
            initialOptions: InAppWebViewGroupOptions(
              crossPlatform: InAppWebViewOptions(
                debuggingEnabled: true,
              ),
            ),
            onWebViewCreated: (InAppWebViewController controller) {
              webView = controller;
            },
            onLoadStart: (InAppWebViewController controller, String url) {},
            onLoadStop: (InAppWebViewController controller, String url) {},
          ))
        ])),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Got the same issue on Android side with `webview_flutter: ^0.3.18+1`.
I found a solution to pause the video by requesting audio focus again in the `onPause` callback of host `Activity`.

```
val audioManager = activity.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE) as AudioManager

if (audioManager.isMusicActive) {
    if (Utils.hasOreoSDK26()) {
        val audioAttributes = AudioAttributes.Builder()
                .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_MEDIA)
                .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_MUSIC)
                .build()
        val audioFocusRequest = AudioFocusRequest.Builder(AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT)
                .setAudioAttributes(audioAttributes)
                .setAcceptsDelayedFocusGain(true)
                .setWillPauseWhenDucked(true)
                .setOnAudioFocusChangeListener(
                        { focusChange -> Timber.i(">>> Focus change to : %d", focusChange) },
                        Handler())
                .build()
        audioManager.requestAudioFocus(audioFocusRequest)
    } else {
        audioManager.requestAudioFocus({ }, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
                AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT)
    }
}
```

Also check [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5946698/how-to-stop-youtube-video-playing-in-android-webview/59528415#59528415).

Comment: rayworks this is such a Hack XD but it works so bows to you fo adding that here. 
I hope they will handle this properly in flutter-webview.

Answer (score 0):

```dart
@override
void dispose() {
  super.dispose();
  _controller.loadRequest(Uri.parse('about:blank'));
}
```

Loading `about:blank` resets the webview state and release page resources (including any running JavaScript, like video or audio).

More info: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/119616#issuecomment-1419991144