# Android ads slow performance very much

Tags: android, multithreading, ads

I have been experimenting with BANNER ads on my Android app, following [this](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start) guide. When the ad load and is being presented a significant FPS drop is observed. This is very frustrating experience for the user, because View animations are core part of my app and they look awful in low FPS. 
 Everything runs fine when I set the adView to `View.GONE`. I don't know where this problem might be originating from. I'm not sure how the UI thread becomes so heavily loaded with a simple BANNER ad... Any suggestions here? 
This problem is present both in my emulator and real Android device.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Google AdView has WebView with a lot of animation inside. It will heats up all mobile CPU.

Summing up it's normal. I have the same situation in my applications. AdView take 30% of CPU. I tried to find any solution but it's known issue. Below links can help you optimize your banners but you have to know that, it will always take some of CPU.

[stackoverflow - admob banners cause high cpu usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19446231/admob-banners-cause-high-cpu-usage)

[stackoverflow - webviewcorethread used by admob adview is using high cpu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12884433/webviewcorethread-used-by-admob-adview-is-using-high-cpu-even-when-parent-activi)

[stackoverflow - android admob consuming more cpu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20973834/android-admob-consuming-more-cpu)

[pzoleeblogen - how to solve adview cpu consuming](https://pzoleeblogen.wordpress.com/2014/07/08/android-how-to-solve-adview-cpu-consuming/)

Please vote up my answer if I help you. 
Have fun.

Comment: So... is it a bug in the ad system?

Comment: I think so. Maybe try display AdView only in MENU? Last one link is helpful to optimize CPU usage when app is background.

Comment: It is helpful but it does not answer my question, how to prevent this performance drop-down.

Comment: How long will Google take to fix this?

Comment: The problem is, that AdView has WebView inside with a lot of animation. It will always heats up CPU.

Comment: 2 years later and Google Banner ads are still breaking the buttery smoothness that my app exhibits without ads. Can anything be done at this point ?

Comment: 4 years later and the issue is still there

Comment: 5 years later still the same. The ads are taking most of the CPU and the app get slow with unacceptable lagging especially if you have a banner in recyclerview.

Comment: 6 years later I still face lag when using Google ads. My flutter app runs smoothly without ad but with ad it feels like I running app on 512MB ram mobile device.

Comment: 7 years later. Still the same issue. Flutter is a complete joke.

Comment: 7 years later, and still the same.

Comment: 8 years later, has anyone found any solution?

Comment: 8 years later, and still the same - https://www.reddit.com/r/admob/comments/17i9ekk/admob_banner_ads_impacting_android_vitals_seeking/