# Mobile Website - How to keep process alive on client side in mobile browser in Android?

Tags: browser, mobile-website, mobile-browser

I am new to mobile website development, and facing this issue where I want to refresh data on the website in every 30 sec which is invoked from the client side and server provides the data in response. Problem is when I close the browser or when the browser goes in background it stops working. Is there any thing we can do to make this thing possible?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the [Android Developers - Processes and Threads](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html) guide. You'll get a deeper introduction to how process life-cycles work and what the difference is between the states for background- and foreground processes.

Answer (score 0):

You could embed your web app in a WebView. This way you could deal with the closing browser case: you could provide a means to "exit" the app that involves closing only your container activity. That way the timers you have registered in javascript will still be running in the 'WebViewCoreThread'. This is an undesirable behavior and a source of problems, but you can take advantage of it if you want (just make sure you don't run UI-related code there). I've never tested this in Kit Kat (which uses a different WebView based on Chrome) but works for previous versions, as I described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15900282/phonegap-javascript-timer-still-running-after-closing-droidgap-activity).

Now the user can always close any app. Even without user interaction, the OS can kill your app on low memory. So just give up on long-running apps that never end, because the OS is designed in such a way this is simply not possible.

You could go native and schedule Alarms using the AlarmManager.

Answer (score 0):

Just checked this out on the Android KitKat WebView and as per Mister Smith's comments the javascript will continue executing in the background until the Activity is killed off:

Just tested with this running in a WebView:

http://jsbin.com/EwEjIyaY/3/edit

My gut instinct is that if the user has moved your application into the background, there seems little value in performing updates every 30 seconds, it makes more sense to just start updating again once the user opens the device up and cache what information you currently have available to you.

As far as Chrome for Android goes the same is happening, as Chrome falls into the background the javascript is still running.

If you are experiencing different behaviour then what exactly are you seeing and can you give us an example?